# How to connect BME280 to ATmega328?

Tags: arduino, pcb, i2c, atmega

I tried to connect a [BME280](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/media/boschsensortec/downloads/datasheets/bst-bme280-ds002.pdf) sensor to an Arduino Uno. After a successful experiment, I decided that I needed to transfer the sensor and the microcontroller to a separate board without unnecessary strapping. How can I attach the BME280 connection diagram to the ATmega328 with minimal strapping?

[image]

*If I understood everything correctly, then the connection diagram of the BME280 to the ATmega328 looks like this.*

Comment: Not sure I understand your question -- surely the connection diagram will be the same?

Comment: There's many ways to connect it, e.g. SPI and I2C. If you already had a successful experiment, why not use the same method that you know it works?

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please can you edit your question and add some missing information. Show your own work and findings so far in detail with a schematic and links to the parts you describe. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: @DamienD the bme 280 sensor has 8 pins for connection, but 6 are output on the divorced sensor for ease of connection via i2c, and I don't have circuits like 8 channels connected to work with only 6.

Comment: Are you asking what's the minimum number of connections required to talk to the sensor via i2c?

Comment: You only need to connect SDA(I2C), SCL(I2C) and GND between Arduino and BME280. Power supplies can be separated.

Comment: Are you planning on designing your own board with its own micro? If so the connections would be done by the copper traces and the pull ups mounted on that board.

Comment: @Ralph That is, I only need to connect 4 pins from the sensor to the microcontroller to the arduino pins, and leave the other 4 pins not connected?

Comment: @DamienD I'm asking for the minimum connection scheme of the sensor to the microcontroller with the minimum strapping for their operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The connection diagram for I2C is shown in figure 17 of the datasheet.

[image]

Note that some pins are connected locally, only VDDIO/SCL/SDA/GND need to be carried over to the microcontroller.

The address bit can be fixed to GND or VDDIO, it does not have to be connected to an I/O pin of the microcontroller.

VDD and VDDIO can be connected together to 3.3V. Be careful with Arduino, the sensor cannot accept 5V on any pin. If the Uno runs on 5V you will need level shifters for SDA and SCL. If you're using a breakout board (eg. from sparkfun or adafruit) these might already be on the board. If you're making your own PCB you will need to add these yourself.

Comment: Added a connection diagram, can you see?

Comment: @АндрейАлександров Your diagram has errors so it does not match the diagram in this answer.

Comment: @Justme Can you point out the mistakes I made? It is for connection errors.

Comment: @АндрейАлександров CSB is wrongly connected and R1, R2 are missing.

Comment: You probably also want to connect the VDDIO pin to VDD if they are going to be the same (do check that VDD is 3.3V not 5V)

Comment: @DamienD thanks for the help!

Comment: @АндрейАлександров Dot on the lines means they are connected to each other. So your SCL+SDA+VDDIO are shorted, be sure to fix that :)

Comment: Those are the types of errors that are easy to spot in layout phase at the latest. All the pins would have been tied to Vcc or GND.